# Splitting dataframe at underscore within a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have rows in a dataframe that I want to split on a *range* of underscores, and save the split values into new columns.

```
    Type                                            Name
  Parent                               ABC_US_Test_en-us        
   Child    ABC_12252020_US_Test_Natl_en-us_Home-vs-Away
Subchild                                          break1
```

For example, I want to split `ABC_12252020_US_Test_Natl_en-us_Home-vs-Away` into a column for `US_Test_Natl_en-us` and another column for `Home-vs-Away`, so that the output looks like:

```
    Type                                            Name                  Type       Matchup
  Parent                               ABC_US_Test_en-us        
   Child    ABC_12252020_US_Test_Natl_en-us_Home-vs-Away    US_Test_Natl_en-us  Home-vs-Away
Subchild                                          break1
```

Said another way, I want to take everything *between* the 2nd and 6th underscore and save that to a new column, and everything *after* the 6th underscore and save it to another new column.

Comment: Why did you pick that split?  Is there some logic to picking where to split?

Comment: Yes, there's a naming convention that uses underscores and I need to store certain parts of it into their own columns. But the pieces I need to extract will always be between a specified range (i.e., I want everything between the 2nd and 6th underscore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets use a regex pattern to extract the matching groups between 2 and 6th underscore.

```
cols = ['Type1', 'Matchup']
df[cols] = df['Name'].str.extract(r'.*?_.*?_(.*?_.*?_.*?_.*?)_(.*)')
```

Result

```
       Type                                          Name               Type1       Matchup
0    Parent                             ABC_US_Test_en-us                 NaN           NaN
1     Child  ABC_12252020_US_Test_Natl_en-us_Home-vs-Away  US_Test_Natl_en-us  Home-vs-Away
2  Subchild                                        break1                 NaN           NaN
```

Regex details

- `.*?_`: Match any character zero or more times but as few times as possible followed by a literal underscore.

Comment: Simple and effective, you can also generate the regex programmatically, or use `r'(?:[^_]*_){2}((?:[^_]*_){3}[^_]+)_(.*)'` where `2`/`3` can be customized ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': [
        'ABC_US_Test_en-us',
        'ABC_12252020_US_Test_Natl_en-us_Home-vs-Away',
        'break1',
        'a_a_b_b_b_b_c_c']})

def get_infix(txt):
    parts = txt.split('_')
    if len(parts) >= 7:
        return '_'.join(parts[2:6])
    return ''

def get_suffix(txt):
    parts = txt.split('_')
    if len(parts) >= 7:
        return '_'.join(parts[6:])
    return ''

df['infix'] = df.Name.apply(get_infix)
df['suffix'] = df.Name.apply(get_suffix)
df
```

```
    Name                                         infix              suffix
0   ABC_US_Test_en-us                            
1   ABC_12252020_US_Test_Natl_en-us_Home-vs-Away US_Test_Natl_en-us     Home-vs-Away
2   break1                                       
3   a_a_b_b_b_b_c_c                              b_b_b_b                c_c
```

In general, you can use `string.split(delimiter)` to split a string on a character and `'character'.join(list)` to join.